# wpf datagrid user add row celldatatemplate value rides

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have some strange problem.

I have

```
<Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Дата выдачи" Width="130" >
   <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate >
            <Custom:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding LicenseDateStart}" />
        </DataTemplate>
   </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and this

```
 public ObservableCollection<OrgInfoProftraining> ListOrgInfoProftraining
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<OrgInfoProftraining>(_ListOrgInfoProftraining);
        }
        set
        {
            _ListOrgInfoProftraining = value.ToList();
            OnPropertyChanged("ListOrgInfoProftraining");

        }
    }
```

I fill the first row, then click to another control (row lose focus) and datepicker (or its value) rides to row 2. Why?
When after filling row1 I click to Enter, it is work correct.

[image]

P.S. I guess it can be ObservableCollection, it can react to changes in templatecolumn and create new item when I select date on datepicker...

Answer (score 0):

Well, when we use MVVM and datagrid, when we add new row to datagrid, we can't catch event row creating, so view-model do not know about new elements.

I have added two buttons "add" and "remove" and it is ok.
Not good solution may be, but it fast =)

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because the cell template is reused for the next row, so with some assumptions here is a solution

you need to separate cell template and editing template or atleast have IsEnabled set to false in non edit mode

eg

```
<Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Дата выдачи"
                               Width="130">
    <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LicenseDateStart}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Custom:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding LicenseDateStart}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

or

```
<Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Дата выдачи"
                               Width="130">
    <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Custom:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding LicenseDateStart}" IsEnabled="False"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Custom:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding LicenseDateStart}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```